# Check whether user is anonymous in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have read the document in AngularFire 1 about Authentication. However, I cannot find out how to check whether the current user is anonymous.

Here is what I tried

```
.controller('IndexCtrl',['$scope','$route','Auth', function($scope,$route,Auth){


    //Check whether user is existent
    $scope.isExistent = function(){
       var isIt = true;
       if(firebaseUser.isAnonymous()){
         isIt = false;
         console.log("is anonyous");
       }
       return isIt;
    }; 
}]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late but the firebase user object has the property isAnonymous within it. Thus calling it as a property instead of a function should do the trick

```
$scope.isExistent = function(){
   var isIt = true;
   if(firebaseUser.isAnonymous){
     isIt = false;
     console.log("is anonyous");
   }
   return isIt;
};
```